# working with a library in a different folder python

Tags: python

I have a directory called "code". Within that directory I have to sub directories:

lib:
Holds a python module I've created

src: 
Holds the python source code calling the module.

When I try to run the code, the import statement is not seeing the module in a separate folder. How do I make the two files interact without changing directories?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Comment: Suggest look up the differences between Python [modules](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) and [packages](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages).  In general packages require an `__init__.py` file and go in sub-folder in the same place as the script(s) calling them.  A module is just a single file containing Python definitions and statements - also in the same folder as the script that is importing it.

Answer (score 0):

Trying this, `from ../target_directory.library import module`.
`../` means going up in directory depth.

I hope it helps.